# how to align navigation horizontally and center it, with responsive CSS preferably

Tags: css

How to center navigation horizontally inside the div? The CSS should be responsive preferably.

HTML:

```
<nav id="centermenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Specialities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
```

well, the css was, and changed the left: 50% to 25%, nada. hope this was enough

```
#centermenu {
float: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #011;
background: #ffe;
overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

#centermenu ul {
float: left;
clear: left;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
left: 50%;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}


#centermenu ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
margin: 1em;
padding: 1em;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try text-align: center on centermenu? It's basic but you never indicated what you've already tried

Comment: Should the menu-items be in one line? Or retain their `display: list-item` state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your browser is **not rendering in quirks mode**. You should have a DOCTYPE specified on the first line of the HTML file to render in standards mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In standards mode, this works (tested and working for me):

```
#centermenu {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #011;
background: #ffe;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#centermenu ul {
list-style: none;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}


#centermenu ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
margin: 1em;
padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was using HTML5 as you noticed, in Chrome, doubt thats the case. Thank you for effort

Comment: Revised my answer. I'm also using Chrome. Renders fine for me. Perhaps check for cascading styles.

Answer (score 2):

```
#centermenu {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#centermenu > ul {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
  overflow:auto; 
}

#centermenu > ul > li {
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u need to specified the width for ul, if you use margin: 0 auto;  no need float: left; or left: 50%

```
#centermenu ul {
margin: 2 auto;
display: block;
width: 600px;
}
```

or make ul display inline;

```
#centermenu ul {
display: inline;
}
```